# How to return all regex match groups in Snowflake?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to split a string into different parts, but the split is more complex than the [`SPLIT()` function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split) can handle (using a simple separator).

Is there any way to use a regular expression to return all of the match groups in one single call?

***The examples below have been made overly simple in order to keep the question succinct. The real strings & patterns are much more complex.***

For example, I wish the example below would return `["abc", "!@#", "123"]`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc-!@#_123', '^(abc)-(!@#)_(123)$', 1, 1, 'ie', ALL);
```

But instead it must be done in multiple calls (one per capturing group), which becomes cumbersome when there are lots of groups:

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc-!@#_123', '^(abc)-(!@#)_(123)$', 1, 1, 'ie', 1),
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc-!@#_123', '^(abc)-(!@#)_(123)$', 1, 1, 'ie', 2),
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc-!@#_123', '^(abc)-(!@#)_(123)$', 1, 1, 'ie', 3);
```

However, things get more tricky when there are groups with multiple matches (i.e. when the total number of matched groups is dynamic). In the example below, the third match returns `456` instead of `123`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc-!@#_123_456', '^(abc)-(!@#)(_\\d+)+$', 1, 1, 'ie', 3);
```

I'm thinking a UDF might be the only way?

Comment: A repeating capture group `( part\\d)+` will only ever return the last match. If you want all the matches, you'd need to add another capturing group around it and then split that result e.g. `((?: part\\d)+)`

Answer (score 1):

As Tim mentioned, you can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) . In which case you'd want to remove the anchors and then just search for something like `part\d+` or something more specific.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('part1 part2 part3 part4', 'part\\d+', 1, 1, 'i');
```

[image]

(Note the escaping of the `\d` as well.)

Also, if you need an array of all possible matches, can't you just use alternation instead of all the capture groups? For example:

[image]

Comment: Please don't copy my answer, make a trivial change, and then repost.

Comment: I think I may have made my question confusing by oversimplifying the string & pattern. I'll update it to something more complex...

Comment: @MarcoRoy updated, is that what you're looking for -- or do you want something like regex.split? where you can use something like multiple separators.

Comment: Ah, so simple that I didn't think of it... Yeah, I might be able to make it work with alternation.  It's not about the separators in this case, but the capturing groups (a separator between two groups could be included in another group).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL` to find all matches:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL('a1_a2a3_a4A5a6', 'part[[:digit:]]+') AS matches
FROM yourTable
```

The above will return an array of all matches.  To access a certain element/match from the above array, we can use `GET()`:

```sql
SELECT GET(REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL('a1_a2a3_a4A5a6', 'part[[:digit:]]+'), 1) AS second_match
FROM yourTable
```

The above returns the second match.

Comment: This the returns all the matches for one single pattern. I'm looking to return all the capturing groups within one match.

Comment: What is the exact output you want?  Do you want a separate column for each match?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as I can access all the capturing groups. Could be multiple columns, an array, a JSON/VARIANT object, whatever.

Comment: I've updated my question to point out how this simple solution does not work.